# How to preserve horizontal space in itextsharp text extraction

Tags: itext

I have a pdf file with the following format.

texthere \t\t texthere  \t\t\ ttexthere
texthere \t\s\t texthere  \s\s\s\t texthere

were \s-space \t - horozontal tab.
But when I applied itextsharp simpleextractionstrategy to extract text it gives the following text.

texthere texthere texthere
texthere texthere texthere

It appears that no matter how long the horizontal space is it just replace it with a single space. Is there a way to keep preserve the actual long space in itextsharp?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the fact that PDF is not a structured text format. What appears to be a normal paragraph text in a PDF rendered could be composed of hundreds of small text chunks, not necessarily in the logical order in which they appear on the page. Many factors including character and word spacing, horiztonal scaling, font size etc. collectively decide where a text chunk will be DRAWN.

The class SimpleTextExtractionStrategy and its elder sister LocationTextExtractionStrategy do a simple job of compare the X,Y location of these text chunks and decide whether one comes before or after the other chunks and append them accordingly to the output string. They do not take care of the amount of horizontal space that is between two chunks.

Beware! Converting a PDF to properly structured text can be far more complex than you might have imagined, but if you're interested, you'll need to modify LocationTextExtractionStrategy (or write your own strategy) and compare text chunks and insert multiple spaces or tabs into the output string based on the horiztonal distance between the end of last chunk and the start of the current one. As I said before, this can be quite complicated, but this should give you a starting point.

Shujaat